# Do anyone knows where nginx does header validations?

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Does anyone knows what characters Nginx didn't allow it in request header name and which module does this check ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Nginx [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#ignore_invalid_headers)

> Valid names are composed of English letters, digits, hyphens, and
> possibly underscores (as controlled by the underscores_in_headers
> directive)

In the source code, it is verified in `ngx_http_request.c` with a function call to `ngx_http_parse_header_line()`.

Comment: I don't agree here because if you send a request with a header containing like `, : etc. it works well.

Comment: In your question you said `request header name` which is different from the header value. I gave you an answer for the header name.

Comment: Yes i meant the same.  I send the request curl -I localhost:80 -H 'Ab!: sbn' and if you see header name contain ! then also i got 200 response ok. Please correct me if i understood incorrectly.

Comment: That might be because `ignore_invalid_headers` might be turned on by default. If you turn the option off, you will get a `Bad Request` error.

Comment: But for some character like &{}[] etc. its says Bad Request.

Comment: Can you post your nginx config and all the information you have in the question? Going back and forth in the comments is a waste of time.